# Animate UITableView change

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a two row tableview (username and password) and when the user hits enter it tries to login and switches the two cells to a single loading cell. While I am going from 2 to 1 cell, the new cell is twice as large (minus 1 px for the separator). I would like to fade between the two states.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use two table views instead. And when user logs in fadeout the present tableview to show the tableview below it.

Well this is a suggestion only.